# How to fix the error: value of type `Vec<String>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&str>?

Tags: rust

I have this simple code, which is supposed to split a string into a vector

```
fn solution(s: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    s.split(",").collect::<Vec<String>>()
}
```

This fails with the following error:

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `Vec<String>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&str`
    --> src/main.rs:172:18
     |
172  |     s.split(",").collect::<Vec<String>>()
     |                  ^^^^^^^ value of type `Vec<String>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&str>`
     |
     = help: the trait `FromIterator<&str>` is not implemented for `Vec<String>`
     = help: the trait `FromIterator<T>` is implemented for `Vec<T>`
```

I got the code to compile by modifying it to:

```
fn solution(s: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    s.split(",").map(|s| s.to_string()).collect::<Vec<String>>()
}
```

But I am not sure why this works? I am also not sure if this is the most optimal way to go about this.

What is the best way to fix such

```
value of type `Vec<String>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&str>
```

errors?

Comment: Why not split it into `Vec<&str>`? BTW, you don't need the turbofish in these examples.

Comment: Another way of looking at the error: How can you turn `&str` into `String`? And how can you apply that to every item in the iterator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `collect` you dont transform the data inside the collection, you only **collect** an iterator into an specified collection. Thus, although trivial, Rust won't transform a &str into a String

if you would declare `solution` as

```
fn solution(s: &str) -> Vec<&str> {
    s.split(",").collect()
}
```

your program would compile.

In order to turn one iterator into another you use [Iterator::map](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map)

```
fn main() -> Result<(), i32> {

    let result = solution("Foo, Var");
    println!("{:?}", result);

    return Ok(());
}

fn solution(s: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    s.split(",").map(|x|x.to_string()).collect()
}
```

You can map the result returned by `split()` into an Vect of Strings because the `struct` Split has an implementation for [IntoInter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/struct.Split.html#impl-IntoIterator-for-Split%3C%27a%2C%20P%3E)

Look at this example, maybe it becomes a bit more obvious why there's a compiler error.

```
fn double(vect: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i64> {
    vect.into_iter().collect()
}
```

you have to tell Rust how to implement the transformation.
i.e

```
fn main() -> Result<(), i32> {
    println!("{:?}", double(vec![1, 2]));
    return Ok(());
}

fn double(vect: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i64> {
    vect.into_iter().map(|x|(x as i64)*2 ).collect()

}
```

Comment: You mentioned "Rust won't transform a &str into a String" are there any types involving usage of collect where Rust helps with conversion? or every usage of collect does not do any conversion?

Comment: It's a bit comvoluted but... [collect](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/traits/iterator.rs.html#1832-1834) needs to yield a collection. So this collection type needs the [FromIterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/traits/collect.rs.html#122) trait. Which for Vec this is the [implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/mod.rs.html#2645). So **I'm guessing** that by changing or implementing the [IntoIterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/traits/collect.rs.html#231) trait of your own struct it should be feasible to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completion:

As I told you in the comment, you can implement the Iterator trait for your `structs` and yield any type you want, but I do think this goes against the pedantic nature of Rust

```
struct StringCount {
    count: u32,
    max: u32,
}

impl StringCount {
    fn new(initial_val: u32, elements: u32) -> Self {
        StringCount{count: initial_val, max: elements}
    }
}

impl Iterator for StringCount {
    type Item = String;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.count += 1;
        if self.count < self.max {
            Some(self.count.to_string())
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

fn main() -> Result<(), i32> {

    println!("{:?}", count(0, 10));
    return Ok(());
}

fn count(start: u32, end: u32) -> Vec<String> {
    StringCount::new(start, end).collect()

}
```

which should yield the result:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
```